# How to Calculate 2^x mod n = 1 in less than 1 second

Tags: c++, math

I want to write the program that Calculate `2^x mod n = 1` we have `n` is an `integer` but, we should calculate `x`.I wrote the code but my code work too slow in big n.Can you suggest me a good way that work less than 1 second to solve this problem.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int n,cntr=1,cheak;
    cin >> n;
    while (1)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        cheak=pow(2, cntr);
        if (cheak % n == 1)
            break;
        cntr++;
    }
    cout << cntr << endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `pow`, but shift left.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be faster.  Write it up with a short code sample.

Comment: To shift use the bit shift operator which is ">>" (or "<<"). See [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) for more details

Comment: Your code will go into an infinite loop if it never reaches the condition.  You might want to change `while(1)` to be `while (cntr < 64)`.

Comment: This is going to exceed the range of an integer before 64 loops I think.

Comment: @drew_w : True.  They're using `long long int`, so technically they should stop at 63.  I suggested in my answer below to switch to `unsigned long long` which would get them to 64.

Comment: The bigger picture is that for many values, the power of 2 you need is well beyond what would fit in an integer if you represent it directly.  To truly solve the math problem, you need to understand modular multiplication.  I've amended my answer below to show the approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggested modifications to your *current* approach:        <sup><sub>**Note**: a better approach follows!</sub></sup>

- Change your `long long int` to `unsigned long long int`.  This will give you one more bit.
- Change `while (1)` to `while (cntr < 64)`.  The size of `unsigned long long` is likely only 64 bits.  (It's guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, but not larger than that.)  You would then need to check whether your loop succeeded, however.
- Change `cheak` to calculate 2<sup>n</sup> as `1ull << cntr`.   Make *sure* to include the `ull` suffix, which says this is an `unsigned long long`.

The `<<` operator shifts bits to the left.  Shifting all the bits to the left by 1 doubles the integer value of the number, assuming no bits "shifted away" off the left of the value.  So, `1 << n` will compute 2<sup>n</sup>.

The suffix `ull` indicates an integer constant is an `unsigned long long`.  If you omit this suffix, `1` will be treated as an integer, and shift values above 31 will not do what you want.

---

**However**, all of the above are merely *refinements* on your *current* approach.  It's worth understanding those refinements to better understand the language.  They don't, however, look at the bigger picture.

[Modular multiplication](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/applied-math/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-multiplication) allows you to find (A * B) mod C as ( (A mod C) * (B mod C) ) mod C.  How does that help us here?

We can rewrite the entire algorithm in a way that only limits `N` and `X` to the precision of the machine integers, and not 2<sup>N</sup>:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int modulus;
    unsigned int raised = 2;
    int power = 1;

    std::cin >> modulus;

    if (modulus % 2 == 1)
    {
        while (raised % modulus != 1)
        {
            raised = ((unsigned long long)raised * 2) % modulus;
            power++;
        }

        std::cout << power << std::endl;
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "modulus must be odd" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The cast to `unsigned long long` above allows `modulus` to be as large as 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits, without the computation overflowing.

With this approach, I was able to very quickly find answers even for very large inputs.  For example, `111111111` returns `667332`.  I verified 2<sup>677332</sup> mod 111111111 == 1 using the arbitrary precision calculator `bc`.

It's very fast.  It computed 2<sup>2323860</sup> mod 4294967293 == 1 in less than 0.07 seconds on my computer.

---

**Epilog**:  This highlights an important principle in programming:  Really, this was a math problem more than a programming problem.  Finding an efficient solution required knowing more about the problem domain than it did knowing about C++.  The actual C++ code was trivial once we identified the correct mathematical approach.

It often goes this way, whether it's the mathematics or some other algorithmic aspect.  And, it shouldn't surprise you to learn that *discrete mathematics* is where many of our graph and set algorithms come from.  The programming language itself is a small piece of the big picture.

Comment: What happens when you feed it 4000000007?

Comment: @tmyklebu : That one took a mighty 56 seconds, and returned 2000000003.

Comment: @tmyklebu : I guess that means there's another layer of math that ought to be applied here?

Comment: Shanks's baby-step-giant-step will find you the order in all cases.  Faster:  You can mess around with prime factorisation and Chinese remaindering to reduce the composite case to the prime power case.  You can probably use Hensel lifting or something to reduce prime powers to primes.  Subtracting one solves the prime case.

Comment: @tmyklebu : Ah, I was not familiar with it.  But, had this been a performance critical aspect of my application, I would have dug further into the math texts.  BTW, your name's familiar... I think I've seen you on LWN or the like?

Comment: Trond Myklebust maintains Linux NFS.  I'm a different guy, and I don't maintain Linux NFS.

Comment: @tmyklebu : Ah, ok.  :-)  Anyway, thanks for the reference to the more advanced algorithm.  It's clear that my number theory only goes so far.

Comment: @tmyklebu : BTW, something amusing:  I set `bc` on computing the expression `2^2000000003 % 4000000007` over four hours ago.  It's still chugging away.  I'm curious how long it'll take to complete the calculation.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For each `k` between 1 and `ceil(sqrt(n))`, compute `2^k mod n` and `2^(k ceil(sqrt(n))) mod n`.  Then compute the modular inverse of each `2^k`.  Sort all of the `inverse(2^k)`s into an array `foo` and the `2^(k ceil(sqrt(n))`s into an array `bar`.  There will be at least one value in common between the two arrays; find it.  Say `inverse(2^a) = 2^(b ceil(sqrt(n)))`. Then `2^(a + b ceil(sqrt(n))) = 1 (mod n)`.

Answer (score 1):

How's your professor's sense of humor?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << 0 << '\n'; }
```

always prints a correct answer to the problem as stated.

Comment: Probably should have asked for x : 2^x == -1 mod n. -- But perhaps it really was a test of how awake the students are. You might want to include some type of dummy input or parameter processing, just to be specific to the task.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` is quite expensive in calculations, but if you have 2 as its first argument, you can better do a shift left, as shift left is equal to multiplying by 2:

```
cheak = (1 << cntr);
```

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, `2^x` is equivalent to `1 << x`.

Comment: That's slightly faster, but for native-sized integers both are fast enough to do (at least) thousands of times per second, so that's clearly *not* OP's problem given that the choice of types limits the loop to a few dozen iterations. That and the fact that your answer contains no other information tempts me to downvote.

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler do that? Is there any reason why the compiler would be so stupid as to miss that blatantly obvious optimisation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: for whatever reason, G++ doesn't apply it.  Probably for reasons of correctness around `errno`?  Although, it still won't optimize it even if I wrap the `pow` in an `if` statement that guarantees `pow(2,x)` returns something that fits in an `int`.  I'm going to guess that the compiler writers didn't see it as worth fixing.